# Custom Image Thumbnails of Different Sizes

Tags: custom-post-types, images, post-thumbnails

I have a Custom Post Type which contains custom fields for uploading images of different types for a portfolio site.

For example: (logos, websites, print-ads, etc...).

I plan on uploading images of all different sizes and aspect ratios, but I need to have a smaller size (thumbnail) of a specific (and different) size for each image type. I also need functionality to crop these thumbnails manually.

Logo thumbs -> 200x200

Website thumbs -> 450x200

print-ad thumbs -> 200X400

etc...

I've been toying with a couple plugins: [Post Thumbnail Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-thumbnail-editor/) and [Multiple Post Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-post-thumbnails/). These seem to be too buggy in WordPress 3.3 and they don't appear to do exactly what I want though.

I could of course just upload 2 different versions of each image and use the crop tool in the backend to get them to the right size but I would love a more elegant approach.

I guessewhat I am really looking for is some advice.

- Should I keep fighting with existing plugins and try to get something
  working?
- Should I try to develop my own? (I'm pretty decent with
  php/javascript but have only written extremely simple wp plugins as
  of yet)?
- Should I give up and use the dirty (upload 2 versions of
  each) approach?

What's the best option to handle this type of situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code to your functions.php

```
if(function_exists('add_theme_support'))
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');

// Set the thumbnail size
add_image_size('custom_logo', 200, 200, true );
add_image_size('custom_website_thumb', 450, 200, true );
add_image_size('custom_print_ad_thumb', 200, 400, true );
```

Put this in your post template where you want to see the image.

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'custom_logo'); ?>
```

You can also wrap it in a link like this.

```
 <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_id) ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?>"> <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'custom_logo'); ?></a>
```

You can see the Wordpress Codex for more exploitation.

Remember to set the images as a featured image on upload to be able to use it.

[Codex Link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails)

Comment: thank you for the advice!  I think I already checked this out though, and, correct me if I am wrong, but this automatically crops the image.  Ideally, I need to be able to choose where the image crops.  That being said, I think Ill use this technique right now, and have a custom field for an alternate image to specify if the default cropping is bad.

Comment: @Zach L.  Yes, it does not let you control where the image crops.  I did not know that you needed the control.  I have not tried it yet but there may be a solution at this link.  [Control Wordpress Crops](http://shailan.com/781/how-to-change-post-thumbnail-crop-position-in-wordpress/)

Comment: bummer... looks like this link only shows how to change how wordpress automatically crops the images, but does not give any hints as to how I might add this functionality to the backend